# turn off auto-escape in matplotlib w/ pgf backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I cannot find an answer to this.

I am rendering plots for a latex document using matplotlib. To have the best "looks" I use the PGF backend, which works very well for most of what I do. However, at the moment I cannot generate one of my figures, because the PGF backend appears to be auto-escaping characters.

My plots are generated using this setup:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('pgf')              # PGF backend

pgf_with_latex = {                      # setup matplotlib to use latex for output
    "text.usetex"  : True,              # use LaTeX to write all text
    "pgf.texsystem": "lualatex",        # change this if using xetex or lautex
    "font.family"  : "serif",
    "font.serif"   : [],                # blank entries should cause plots to inherit fonts from the document
    "font.sans-serif": [],
    "font.monospace": [],
    "axes.labelsize": 10,               # LaTeX default is 10pt font.
    "font.size": 10,
    "legend.fontsize": 8,               # Make the legend/label fonts a little smaller
    "xtick.labelsize": 8,
    "ytick.labelsize": 8,
    "figure.figsize": figsize(),        # default fig size of 0.9 textwidth
    "pgf.preamble": [
      r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",    # use utf8 fonts becasue your computer can handle it :)
      r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",        # plots will be generated using this preamble
      r"\usepackage{amsmath}",            # math stuff
      r"\usepackage{siunitx}",            # SI units
      r"\usepackage{mhchem}",             # chemical elements
    ],
"text.latex.unicode" : True
}
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
```

And I plot using this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
ax.set_ylabel(r'not working~~[\SI{1e10}{\m^{-2}}]')

sax = ax.twinx()
sax.set_ylabel(r'working~~[\SI{e12}{\m}$^{-2}$]')
plt.savefig('test.pgf')
```

Using Lualatex as an interpreter I import the figure like this:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
   \centering
   \import{}{test.pgf}
   \caption{bla.}
\end{figure}
```

The Latex document has the same packages implemented as the matplotlib preamble. Now the error message I get is this:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \^ invalid in math mode on input line xxx.

! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
\MT@orig@add@accent ...ctor \spacefactor }\accent 
                                              #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
l.xxx ...electfont not working~~[\SI{1e10}{\m\^{-2}}
                                              ]}%
```

As far as I can tell the problem is the escaping being done. This appears to be a problem specific to the PGF backend, since I have generated PDFs etc. fine using a similar setup (different rcparams in that case).

Does anyone know, where the problem is here? Did I miss a configuration?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @DavidG: Thx for the edit.

Maybe a second question would be, whether I can turn the auto-escaping off. I did not find how to do that.